# Swift3 - Get transaction date when restoring In-App Purchase Transactions

Tags: ios, swift, transactions, in-app-purchase

i am trying to restore in-app purchase (non-renewing subscription) in case a user installs the app on a new phone or re-installs it on his phone. I want to get the original purchase date for an in-app purchase using the method

```
 func paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished(_ queue: SKPaymentQueue) {

        for transaction in queue.transactions{
            let t : SKPaymentTransaction = transaction
            let prodID = t.payment.productIdentifier as String
            print("transaction finished",prodID)
            if(prodID == "com.netvariant.FamousFaces.FullAccess"){
                print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>", t.original?.transactionDate)
                print(">>>>>>>>>>>>>", t.transactionDate)
                defaults.set("Y", forKey: "adPurchase")
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: "removeAds"), object: nil)
                print("working")
            }

        }
    }
```

The problem is transaction date in returning nil in both cases. What did i miss in the code ? and is this the best way to handle restored purchases?

I want to get the date to calculate if the users's subscription period (1 month) is over or not. The restore is successful but as i mentioned the date in nil.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) for verify and Perform InApp Purchase. Below code for verify InApp purchase is expired or not. For User this code, your [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) in your project.

```
let appleValidator = AppleReceiptValidator(service: .production)
SwiftyStoreKit.verifyReceipt(using: appleValidator, password: "Enter your inapp secret key") { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let receipt):
        // Verify the purchase of a Subscription
        let purchaseResult = SwiftyStoreKit.verifySubscription(
            type: .autoRenewable, // or .nonRenewing (see below)
            productId: "Enter your inapp product key",
            inReceipt: receipt)

        switch purchaseResult {
        case .purchased(let expiryDate, _):

            print("Product is valid until \(expiryDate)")
        case .expired(let expiryDate, _):

            print("Product is expired since \(expiryDate)")
        case .notPurchased:
            print("The user has never purchased this product")
        }

    case .error(let error):
        print("Receipt verification failed: \(error)")
    }
}
```

Comment: how could i install this library, using Pods?

Comment: Yes you can install using Pods. Check this link : https://cocoapods.org/?q=SwiftyStoreKit

Comment: Thank you. but there is a problem , i purchased the IAP with the sandbox account and the response is always "not purchased". Do i have the library to purchase the product or i can do it from storekit?

Comment: How you testing InApp Purchase. In device or Simulator? You can perform all thing with SwiftyStorekit like purchase product,Check expired or not, load product etc..

Comment: i am testing on a device , it's working after i purchase the product but if i close or restart the app the expiration date will not return.Any advice?

Comment: Refer this Link : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html In Sandbox, In App Purchase expired in Minutes as per Duration.